# Server Application Unavailable? in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I uploaded, my web application online when i type the url i am getting this error..

```
Server Application Unavailable.
The web application you are attempting to access on this web server is currently unavailable.  Please hit the "Refresh" button in your web browser to retry your request.
```

can you help me thank you.

Comment: If you're hosted, ask your host about it. If it's your own server, give more details.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem just resolved it.See your web config that in which version of .net your application is running. Make a new application pool for that Application in the same version and move your application to that pool.Hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

I had a web site happily deployed and running on our company's IIS server, then yesterday, it stopped working, with this same error, "**Server Application Unavailable.**"

What fixed it for me was to create a *new* App Pool user (accepting all of the defaults), and I got my web site to use this new pool user instead of the default one.

It's a really quick'n'easy thing to try, if you get this error.

I suspect it was caused by another developer deploying a web site to this same IIS server, *also* using the default App Pool user, but their app used a different version of ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

This can almost be absolutely anything. From not having installed the (correct) .NET framework, having selected the wrong application pool in IIS, an invalid web.config file, whatsoever.

The problem will *most likely* lie in some misconfiguration however, and not a 'bug' in the code. But without more detail, I doubt anyone can help.

One thing you can try: check the Windows Eventlog. There might be a more detailed error message in there, under the Application section.

Answer (score 0):

Try registering your asp.net framework once again using `aspnet_regiis.exe` found in your framework installation path. By default it will be found at c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727 folder. you can choose the folder based on your version of framework.

try the following commands -

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -ua
```

This uninstalls all versions

then

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

This installs the version of 2.0

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for numerous reasons. First of all, edit your web.config, find the line that reads < customErrors> and set its mode to Off (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx); this might give you the error details instead of just a single message.

Read http://www.ironspeed.com/Designer/3.2.4/WebHelp/Part_VI/Server_Application_Unavailable.htm for more information.

Comment: This error happens earlier in the cycle: setting the custom errors to Off won't change anything in this case.